# How to expose an EJB 3.1 as a REST Web Service?

Tags: java, web-services, http, ejb, jax-rs

I discovered a new feature in java restful when using EJB 3.1 while reading an article at [Adam Bien's](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/ejb_3_1_and_rest) blog.

The thing is that Stateless and Singleton beans can be exposed as root resources. But how?
I tried to do it this way:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
@Path("Hybrid")
public class RESTEJBSample {

    @GET
    @Path("/demo")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String something() {
        return "I am a Hybrid!!!";
    }

}
```

When i call the URL http://localhost:8080/HybridSample/resources/Hybrid/demo i get a 404 error.

Appart of this and just to make sure that JAXRS is is working in my project, i created a simple pojo resource just to test if it works fine.

```
@Path("/genericresource")
public class GenericResource {
    @GET
    @Path("/samplemethod")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String saySomething() {
        return "Something!";
    }
}
```

Here when i call the URL http://localhost:8080/HybridSample/resources/genericresource/samplemethod It works fine!

So my questions are:

- what is missing in my EJB so it can work as a web service resource such as the class GenericResource is doing?
- Is there some extra configuration needed?
- What are the limitations when using EJB as a web service?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to this [NetBeans tutorial about Jersey RESTFul web services](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html), you can decide whether to

> create a subclass of javax.ws.rs.core.Application, all Rest resources
>   will be registered by this class automatically (Java EE 6)

or

> create default Jersey REST servlet adaptor in web.xml.

I have always used the second choice, which consists in adding this to your `web.xml`:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Exposing your REST Web service as an EJB is, to my experience, extremely useful. You can inject it wherever you like, you can inject in it your EntityManager, and you can even use it as a DAO in some simple situations.

Concerning your question / comment about features and limitations: enterprise beans run in the EJB container, whether they are deployed in a war file or not. You can inject into them a JMS ConnectionFactory as a resource as explained in [this section](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncgl.html) of the Java EE 6 Tutorial. Thanks to the injection of a ConnectionFactory, you can send JMS messages. If you want to receive JMS messages asynchronously, you need to define a Message-Driven Bean as explained in [this section](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbpo.html) of the above mentioned tutorial.
I have never tried to extend the same EJB used for a Jersey web-service in order to implement the MessageListener interface, but I think that should be possible as well (if not, you can inject a MDB into your Jersey root Stateless bean).

Finally, you can use Container-Managed transactions as explained [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncij.html). Moreover, from [this NetBeans tutorial](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/javaee-gettingstarted.html):

> In order to have you can see that the application will use the Java
>   Transaction API (JTA) (transaction-type="JTA"). This specifies that
>   the responsibility for managing the lifecycle of entities in the
>   persistence context is assigned to the container.

```
<persistence-unit name="em" transaction-type="JTA">
```

Comment: Good i didnt know the first one :) The web.xml option is also my favoutity, currently my web.xml lookl like that already.
Also i used the Netbeans IDE `New->Webservice` and following a wizard i tick an option that says create web service as Stateless bean. That inserted added the EJB into the .war file and now it works fine. My example works fine now, but i would be also interested in knowing what is happening behind the scene?, what files are being edited by Net Beans? And also what are the limitations of this bean?

Yeah I think this is a really cool feature too.

Comment: NetBeans is not adding anything: the only things that you have to do are to create the Stateless class (RESTEJBSample in your example) and the servlet adaptor in web.xml. The servlet is doing all the magic behind the scenes. Regarding the limitations, I think that you should try to clarify a bit your question.

Comment: When i mention limitations i mean. Are this beans going to be able to behave in the same ways as when deployed in the EJB-Modules? What i mean is is there any need for some kind of manual transaction management?Can they interact with JMS?... Now they are not in the EJB container, they are in a .war file.

Comment: @perissf Hi Perissf, Please solve my problem and guide me. I am in great need for this. Please this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19706788/jersey-rest-web-service-with-activemq-middleware-integration. I want to implement asynchronous communication. Please help and thanks for your time. Please.!!!

Comment: @Kumar sorry I don't have an answer out of the box to your question.

Comment: @perissf I did not get you. Please could you elaborate.

Comment: @perissf I am doing the same in Jersey RestApi . Moreover I would like to make it Asynchronous communication so that I would be handling each request and no request would be missed.