# Converting a stateless EJB3.1 session bean to RESTful web service

Tags: rest, ejb-3.1

I found a very interesting question and also the answer to that

> [How to expose an EJB 3.1 as a REST Web Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9883843/how-to-expose-an-ejb-3-1-as-a-rest-web-service)

which refers to  http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/ejb_3_1_and_rest.

It is a very **useful feature**. My question is whether the session bean needs to be a **singleton** or not? The query I quoted states that it should be a singleton session bean meanwhile the original, the query refers to, does not contain this statement. If it has to be a singleton, could you tell me why?

Thank you also in advance, Tamas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although there are no constraints about the `EJB` type of the class implementing REST (in fact this class doesn't even need to be an `EJB` at all), an easy-to-maintain and scalable approach suggests to use a `Stateless` bean for the purpose.

Have a look at this interesting article: [**RESTful Web services: The basics**, by A. Rodriguez](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-restful/), that has a section on the subject (with title **Be stateless**). From that section, let me quote something:

> Stateless server-side components, on the other hand, are less complicated to design, write, and distribute across load-balanced servers. A stateless service not only performs better, it shifts most of the responsibility of maintaining state to the client application. In a RESTful Web service, the server is responsible for generating responses and for providing an interface that enables the client to maintain application state on its own.

Comment: Thank you for reponding so quickly and in a high-quality manner. The artickle attached was great, also for an overview not only to this specific question.